# Snapping to a enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone have any tips on how i can make a forward snap to a enemy and be able to have a adjustable offset from them?

```
        public Transform Target;
        public new Camera camera;
        public float distance;
       
        private void activateFinisher()
        {
    
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out hit, distance))
                {
                    Debug.Log("hit");
    
    
                    if (hit.transform.CompareTag("Enemy"))
                    {

                        transform.LookAt(Target);
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I say the word offset, I mean a distance away from the enemy. The reason why I want an adjustable distance away from the enemy is so that it does not just go right Infront of the enemy's face. Instead allowing me to be able to implement a fisher animation.

Comment: What offset do you mean? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @pixlhero When I say the word offset, I mean a distance away from the enemy. The reason why I want an adjustable distance away from the enemy is so that it does not just go right Infront of the enemy's face. Instead allowing me to be able to implement a fisher animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Player.position = Enemy.position + Enemy.forward * offset;` should work

[image: example]